# How to get special characters of the body of an email using imap with PhP?

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I'm using imap with php to get the body of my emails.

With what've coded so far, I am not getting the special characters and weird formatting at the end. For instance, if I send myself an email (with a regular email client such as Apple Mail) that says:

> Test with characters é à and some ! that rock.

What I get with php is:

> Test with characters =C3=A9 =C3=A0 and some ! that rock.=

I've tried re-sending the body through the mail function of php with those headers, but I'm still getting the same problem.

```
$headers="From: address@email.com" . "\r\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
mail($sendTo, $message, $noBody, $headers);
```

I've tried `addslashes()`, which didn't help either.

Sample of my code here:

```
$imapLink=imap_open("{".$mailbox."}INBOX",$username,$password);
$mailBoxInfos = imap_check($imapLink);
$mailList = imap_fetch_overview($imapLink,"1:".$mailBoxInfos->Nmsgs);
if(isset($mailList))
{
    $numMess = imap_num_msg($imapLink);
    while($numMess>0) {
        $message = imap_body($imapLink, $numMess);
        $numMess --;
    }
}
$imapClose = imap_close($imapLink);
```

Hope you can help me with that!

Thanks in advance!

Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=XX` you see in your text is called "Quoted-Printable Content". It's used to display character which can't be displayed in 7-bits.

You can use [quoted_printable_decode()](http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode) to convert it back to a readable string.

So this should work:

```
$message = imap_body($imapLink, $numMess);
$message = quoted_printable_decode($message); // <-- add this line
$numMess --;
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot buddy!
And if I send special characters by email, is "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" what I want to display in my header?

It works with my email provider (GMAIL) but some apparently can't see the accents on the emails I'm sending through my system...

Comment: When using charset=UTF-8 you wouldn't need to encode with quoted-printable encoding. So the $message would just contain valid UTF-8 characters. If you want to **display** these characters via PHP, however, you would need to output UTF-8 as well (or convert to the encoding your PHP is using at the time). For instance if you're using ISO-8859-1 as PHP-output you could use [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) to convert the UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2)  Or you could switch your PHP to UTF-8 output with `default_charset = "utf-8";` in php.ini and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of your php. Welcome to the world of encoding ;)

Comment: Holy cow, didn't think encoding was that complex... Thanks a lot Rik, it helped a ton! Have a good one ;)